# Regex to capture a single character that does not capture all words starting with it

Tags: regex

I cannot make a regex that only captures a trailing space or N of spaces, followed by a single letter s.

```
((\s)+(s){1,1})
```

Works but breaks when you start to stress test it, for example it greedily captures words beginning with s.

```
word s word s
word  s
word  suffering
word   spaces
word  s some ss spaces
there's something wrong
words S s
```

[image]

Comment: do u mean like `/\s+(?=s)/gi`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want a single letter `s` to be captured, as opposed to an `s` at the beginning of a longer word, you need to specify a word break `\b` after `s`:

```
\s+s\b
```

[Demo on regex101](https://regex101.com/r/T1Wvdk/1)

Answer (score 1):

If you for example do not want to match in   `s#` you can also assert a whitespace boundary to the right.

**Note** that for a match only, you can omit all the capture groups, and using `(s){1,1}` is the same as `(s){1}` which by itself can be omitted and would leave just `s`

```
\s+s(?!\S)
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/WbPmw8/1)

As `\s` can also match a newline, if you want to match spaces without newlines:

```
[^\S\n]+s(?!\S)
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/VbU6if/1)